# Error: proc macro `main` not expanded: Cannot create expander for

Tags: rust, actix-web, rust-analyzer

I want to run a web server with [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) and [Actix-Web](https://actix.rs/). After following [these steps](https://actix.rs/docs/getting-started/) of their documentation everything works as expected: the server runs on port 8080.

The problem I have is that VSCode shows errors

[image: Screenshot from VSCode with errors]

This error message is shown in the tooltip upon hovering the error in the IDE

> proc macro `main` not expanded: Cannot create expander for /Users/name/Documents/projects/project-rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_web_codegen-b262af45f63000f3.dylib: Io(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: DlOpen { desc: "dlopen(/Users/name/Documents/projects/project-rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_web_codegen-b262af45f63000f3.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Users/name/Documents/projects/project-rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_web_codegen-b262af45f63000f3.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libactix_web_codegen-b262af45f63000f3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libactix_web_codegen-b262af45f63000f3.dylib' (no such file)" } })

Environemnt - macOS Monterey 12.1 (M1)

Comment: See [this rust-analyzer issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/12525). Based on the error message it might be that you're running x86 VSCode but your code is being compiled to arm64.

Comment: I understand that its annoying, but maybe sometimes its OK to just ignore the errors reported by the VSCode while the codebase compiles flawlessly.

FWIW, I also read the answer & it fixed my issue.

Comment: Opening the VSCode command palette and choosing `Developer: Reload Window` solved it for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## VS Code

---

Thanks, @Smitop for the tip

I [reinstalled VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) with universal build and the errors are gone

[image]

P.S. I tried to install the build for Apple Silicon, but it didn't help

## NVIM (macOS, arm64, m1)

---

For those experiencing the same issue in NeoVim, the following steps helped resolve the errors.

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute `rustup toolchain list`

It should print

```
stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
```

3. Copy the `stable-x86_64-apple-darwin` and make it default, by using `rustup default stable-x86_64-apple-darwin`
4. Re-open NeoVim.
5. Errors should disappear

Comment: Installing Apple Silicon or Universal didn't work for me.

Comment: In addition to reinstalling the Universal build of VS Code, I also had to clean the `target/` folder in my project.

Answer (score 6):

For me, **reinstalling VS Code was *not necessary***:

- Go into plugin settings in VSCode, uninstall the Rust-Analyzer plugin
- Restart VS Code
- Reinstall Rust-Analyser

The restart was necessary for me, because otherwise reinstallation would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha: Verify that you have not accidentally added a `rust-toolchain.toml` file in a *subdirectory* (instead of project root) pointing to some other rust version than your global....

Once I moved the `rust-toolchain.toml` to the project root (in a workspace, multi-crate project), and `cargo clean` the issue dissappeared for me!